# When to use arrival versus arrivals

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

We have a new group of shirts we are posting to our website.  It is a group of shirts from a single brand.  Not from multiple brands and not multiple categories (example: shirts and pants) from a single brand.

> New Arrivals This Week

OR

> New Arrival This Week

Comment: "New arrival" would imply only one shirt. Surely, you hope to sell more than that?

Comment: It is a large group of shirts. But one group, one brand, one category.

Comment: The question is, what will your customers think it means? What you know it means is irrelevant. Of course, you could just put "New this week."

Comment: I'm trying to learn what is grammatically correct given the parameters I've provided.

Comment: It depends on what you are counting. If you are counting groups and there is only one group, then you need "New arrival this week". If there is more than one group, then you need "New arrivals this week." It's as simple as that.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the number of shirts but the number of styles, because to the customer they are one in the same. If there is one newly arriving style, arrival. If more than one style, arrivals.

Comment: You have multiple shirt**s** (in the same color and style); hopefully also in multiple size**s**. I would use the plural.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are counting your shirts.

If you currently sell five different shirts, and after the arrival, you will be selling six different shirts, your message should say "**New Arrival This Week**, if afterward, you will be selling seven or more different shirts, use "**New Arrivals This Week**."

You would use "arrival" even if you are getting a shipment of 10,000 identical shirts, since your customers have only one new option.

Another way of thinking about it:

> New Arrivals This Week: Chewy Brain and Serious Fury shirts

or

> New Arrival This Week: Chewy Brain t-shirt

(Thanks to http://www.bandnamemaker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not anticipate ever having more than one new style of shirt arriving at a time, you can say "New Arrival".  However, even in this case, it doesn't sound very good to my ear.

The singular makes me think of a birth announcement.

For a website, it is better to use phrases that are re-usable in the future.  In that sense, "New Arrivals" would be much better.  And it feels more **normal**.

However, I do want to acknowledge what you said about there being just one style, color, etc., for this particular new arrival.